# RemoteDriver using chrome browser fails on dropdown menu

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium-standalon-2.25.0 and chrome is version 13.

Here is the html:

```
<select name="suffix" class="select">
<option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
<option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
</select>
```

Here is the command that I am calling to select one of the options. The other is a variable that I grab from the db and the question is the suffix that I grab from the db. This works in firefox and IE but not chrome:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='" + other + "' and ..[@name='" + question + "']]")).click();
```

This is the Exception that I'm getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: findElement execution failed;
 Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //option[@value='Ms.' and ..[@name='suffix']] because of the following error:
Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 52 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Session ID: bf6368f23db4a2fe27d9b96849af1b1d
Command duration or timeout: 646 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-31-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 134947044387
```

I've been working on this for awhile and my guess is is has to do with my findElement statement. The weird part is that is works fine with FF and IE. Any help would be greatly appreciative. Thanks again.

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the other way...

```
//select[@name='suffix']/option[@value='Ms.']
```

Your XPath query doesn't seem a valid one. It doesn't even make logical sense. Go down the tree, not up it.

Comment: Thanks Arran that was it. I don't know why I decided to go up the tree instead of down it. Actually I'm even surprised it worked in FF and IE.

Answer (score 0):

besides the approach mentioned by **Arran**, also try using css selectors. They work faster than xPaths.

```
String msCssSelector= "select[name='suffix']>option[value='Ms.']"
String mrsCssSelector=  "select[name='suffix']>option[value='Mrs.']"
String mrCssSelector=  "select[name='suffix']>option[value='Mr.']"
```

ALso do not forget to verify found locators in firepath, firebug addon in ffox
[image: locator verify]

*approach 1*

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(msCssSelector)).click();
```

*approach 2* using actions builder API

```
WebElement mnuOptionElement;
mnuOptionElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(mrCssSelector));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
// Move cursor to the Main Menu Element
builder.moveToElement(mnuOptionElement).click();
```

more info about Actions builder you can get [here](http://www.anitpatel.net/2012/02/25/selenium-webdriver-how-to-click-on-a-hidden-link-or-menu/)

*approach 3* using jsExecutor to click on web element. Always works for me in all situations.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+msCssSelector+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Hope this works for you now)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that CSS selectors worked faster than xpath. I will definitely use this in the future.